# Rails 3, Active Record query returns ActiveRecord::Relation object, instead of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I feel like this is a simple problem I'm having due to my misunderstanding of the new ActiveRecord query interface, but take this example:

```
>> Category.first.recipes
=> [ ... ] # array of recipes
```

However:

```
>> Category.where(:id => 1).recipes
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `recipes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000001033dc9e0>
```

What's going on here? why does my `where` method return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object? how can I retrieve the objects from the query here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is actually intentional.

```
Category.where(:id => 1)
# Is Equivalent to Category.all(:conditions => {:id => 1}})
Category.where(:id => 1).first
# Is equivalent of Category.first(:conditions => {:id => 1}})
```

The objects are only retrieved when special methods like first, each etc are called. This is called lazy loading which is a great when you want to cache your views. Read more about why  [here](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface).

Comment: vote down because its not equivalent. `where` returns ActiveRecord::Relation, while the rest returns Array or Model.class

Comment: It is equivalent in the context. That is why I mentioned lazy loading.  But yes, `.where.all` would be equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

```
Category.where(:id => 1).recipes
```

Returns an array. If you simply do `Category.where(:id => 1).first.recipes` it should work.

Answer (score 4):

But if you are just doing a where against the id, use the find method
`Category.find(1)` will return a Category object.
So:
    `Category.find(1).recipes`